# call Rscrit from java

Tags: java, scripting, rjava, jri

I have ensemble of R scripts doing classification staff.
I want to create an graphical interface to my application with java.
I installed rJava and integrate JRI with java and every thing work correctly coz i tried a simple example "calculate the mean of a list".
now i want to call the scripts then call the functions in this scripts in my interface buttons.
I tried:

```
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Rscript /home/allR/functions.R");
```

but how I can now call the functions in this script